# "MyClassLibraryProjectName" targets 'net5.0'. It cannot be referenced by a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2'

Tags: .net, frameworks, version, target, portable-class-library

I have added class library in my current project that have .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2. I have other class library project that have targets 'net5.0. how can I reference library project to my current project.

my error

> '..\demo.csproj' targets 'net5.0'. It cannot be referenced by a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2'.  demo1

I have tried with update framework runtime but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that version difference we can solve with 3 way
**Option 1** - We can change the target framework of .NET project.
*Steps :* RC on Project. -> click on Property -> Application Tab -> Target Framework Dropdown -> Change this to 5.0 or latter version.

**Option 2** - Create .NET Standard Class Library
Common set of API available across different .NET plateform.
*Steps :* Create new class Library Project(.NET Framework) -> Move your all code from class library project to here(new project). ->Solve reference errors -> Reload Project

**Option 3** - also can change target framework from .csproj file of .NET Project

```
<TargetFrameworks>net5.0;netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>
```

My Error was solve with Option 2. Hope you find your solution.